# Light high sound in first 3 gears

Tags: noise, timing-belt

My buckie is giving me a  highlight  sound  on first  3 gears but  this   comes after  changing  a timing  belt     my buckie  is a colt 2.4i petrol engine     help  me please  is it normal    like  that?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you add some more detail to your post?  What's a highlight sound?  And specifically which kind of car do you have?  It's a Mitsubishi, I presume?  Does this sound happen while you're driving, while you're stopped, or both?  Where does the sound seem to be coming from?

Comment: Sounds like the timing belt is too tight, they will whine if over tensioned.